# Modify Rails i18n config during a test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm trying to test a Rails plugin to make sure that the correct action is performed with or without `fallbacks` turned on.  Inside my Dummy application's configuration, I have:

```
module Dummy
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  end
end
```

How can I flip this back to `false` for a specific test?  So far I have tried:

```
Dummy::Application.config.i18n.fallbacks = false
Dummy::Application.configure do |app|
  app.config.i18n.fallbacks = false
end
Rails.application.config.i18n.fallbacks = false
```

All to no avail.

Comment: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/inject-that-rails-configuration-dependency

Comment: @karlingen That is a great way to test a similar situation in rspec, but I don't see how to apply it here?

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question, actually once the app got initialized in the beginning, you couldn't change i18n configuration because it already got memoized with these [codes](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/267489a103d4b99ca73dfa0d4b34c22c8fc6a803/activesupport/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb#L29-L30):

```
# Setup i18n configuration.
def self.initialize_i18n(app)
  return if @i18n_inited
  ...
  @i18n_inited = true
end
```

And `I18n.fallbacks` was set with this [line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/267489a103d4b99ca73dfa0d4b34c22c8fc6a803/activesupport/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb#L95)

```
I18n.fallbacks = I18n::Locale::Fallbacks.new(*args)
```

When you specify the `callbacks` as true, `I18n.fallbacks` has a value of

```
[1] pry(main)> I18n.fallbacks
=> {}
[2] pry(main)> I18n.fallbacks.class
=> I18n::Locale::Fallbacks
```

And `I18n.fallbacks` is used in this [way](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/267489a103d4b99ca73dfa0d4b34c22c8fc6a803/actionview/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb#L47):

```
locales.concat(I18n.fallbacks[I18n.locale]) if I18n.respond_to? :fallbacks
```

As long as `I18n.respond_to? :fallbacks`, the app will always have fallbacks feature turned on.

The method is defined [here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/aee7b3f6072fba3f54798a280bd6007536b039cd/lib/i18n/backend/fallbacks.rb#L13-L23) in I18n:

```
def fallbacks
  @@fallbacks ||= I18n::Locale::Fallbacks.new
end
```

To turn off the fallbacks feature, the only way is to make `I18n.respond_to? :fallbacks` return `false`.

Here you go:

```
class << I18n
  remove_method :fallbacks
end
```

Comment: Larry, thanks for the help.  It looks like that's not the only place that uses fallbacks.  I may just have to leave this test out for now.  I guess I am testing the underlying code anyway, which is just silly.